# sscanf() changs other variables

Tags: c, scanf

I have another function read_line(), which is not shown here; it simply prints out a string message and read an input that the user types in. The following is my main function. I have two printf() functions here and they print out different results while I suppose x is going to keep its value. Does it mean the sccanf() has something to do with changing the value of x? For example, I typed in 250 and the printf() results are 250 and 7565921.

```
 int main(){
   char buffer[100];
   int x;
   char y;

   read_line("x: ", buffer,sizeof(buffer));
   sscanf(buffer, "%d", &x);
   while(1){
       read_line("y: ", buffer,sizeof(buffer));
       printf("%d\n", x);
       sscanf(buffer, "%s", &y);
       printf("%d\n", x);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you think `sscanf(buffer, "%s", &x);` does?

Comment: Sorry I meant &y in this second sscanf. Just changed it in my post.

Comment: Check out the [`man 3 scanf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) page especially where it describes the `%s` conversion. It states:"Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters; the next pointer must be a pointer to character array that is long enough to hold the input sequence and the terminating null byte ('\0'), which is added automatically. The input string stops at white space or at the maximum field width, whichever occurs first."

Comment: Did you mean `sscanf(buffer, " %c", &y);`??  (**note:** the `'space'` before `%c`)

Comment: If I use %c it will only allow me to have 1 character. I mean, if &y points to "abcd" then I could only get 'a'. I deleted my previous comment...at that point I thought I just couldn't use %s here. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is wrong

```
sscanf(buffer, "%s", &x);
```

You are reading a string and `sscanf` writes in the memory pointed to by `&x`,
but `x` is an integer, not a `char` array. That means the depending on the
length of the input, you overflow the memory, because it would write more bytes
than an `int` can hold. This is undefined behaviour and this is why you see
garbage. You probably wanted to do

```
sscanf(buffer, "%d", &x);
```

in the second `sscanf`.

And yes, if you pass `&x` to a subsequent call of `sscanf`, the subsequent call
will obviously change the value of `x`.

**UPDATE**

Now that you've updated your code

```
sscanf(buffer, "%s", &y);
```

This is also wrong. You are passing a pointer to `char`, but it can hold **1**
byte only. A 1 character long strings needs at least 2 bytes, because in C
strings are `'\0'`-terminated. A string is just a sequence of characters that
ends with the `'\0'`-terminating byte.

So in this case `sscanf` is also overflowing the memory and this is once again
undefined behaviour, so anything can happen. `x` changed because of the
overflow.

You have to change your code to this:

```
char y[20];
sscanf(buf, "%s", y);
```

And this would work assuming that the string is no longer than 19 characters.

```
char y[20];
sscanf(buf, "%19s", y);
```

This would ensure that you don't write more than 20 characters. When reading
strings of unknown length specially if they contain white spaces, `sscanf` may not be the best choice, I mean `buf` is
already a string. For that other functions like `strchr` or `strtok` are more appropriate.

Comment: Sorry I meant &y in the second sscanf. I have edited in my post.

Comment: @OptatootatpO I've updated my answer addressing you change in the question.